# Pod Install Braintree, Undefined symbols for architecture when using their Drop in View Controller

Tags: objective-c, braintree

```
#import <Braintree/Braintree.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BTDropInViewController *vc = [[BTDropInViewController alloc] init];
```

The import succeeds. I have a warning about an unused variable on the last line but no error.

In compilation, however:

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`

I tried removing arm64 from my project & target.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The unused variable warning is because you aren't using `vc`, which is pretty self-evident.

For the symbol not found, check if the import works. For starters, is the pod being added to this target?

Comment: @gran_profaci yes, the import alone without creating the *vc will compile successfully. The pod shows up as a folder, I don't see a target list?

Comment: You added the Braintree pod on which target? You have to specify it in your podfile.

Comment: @gran_profac how so? The tutorial just says "pod Braintree"

Comment: @gran_profac there's only one target for my project, besides the Pods project.